# Unable to read multipartfile in spring boot 3.2.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data, spring-boot-3, multipartfile

Currently i move from Springboot 2 to Springboot 3.2.2. But i got an issue where i unable to upload file to the controller.

Before i use `commons-fileupload` dependency  but it use javax servlet (i move it to jakarta servlet). Try using commons-fileupload2-jakarta. But still not working.

Try to submit file using ajax with formdata. Same case happen 405 with the same error like below

What am i missing?

Error:

```
405 

Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/lmsadmin] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided)
```

pom.xml

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    
    <!-- org json ConfigApps-->
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
            
            
    <!-- Unirest -->
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Header Footer -->
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- GSON Mapping -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- apache poi -->
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- base.Splitter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>32.1.3-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- unbescape -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.unbescape</groupId>
        <artifactId>unbescape</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!--zxing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Java melody -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
        <artifactId>javamelody-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Kode Haus -->
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    
</dependencies>
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    
    public @ResponseBody String dopost(HttpSession session, @RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        
}
```

JSP

```
<form id="formInput" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="controller/upload" method="POST">
<input type="file" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" id="files0" name="file" />

</form>
```

**UPDATE:**

Multipart config added after *@Controller*

```
@MultipartConfig(
        location="/tmp",
          fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024,
          maxFileSize=1024*1024*5,
          maxRequestSize=1024*1024*25) // 20MB)
```

application.properties

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.http.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.http.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Comment: Spring Framework 6 (used by Spring Boot 3) doesn't support Comons Fileupload anymore (not the old nor the new version). Only the standard Servlet API file upload is supported. Also remove `jakarta.servlet-api` as those are already included in the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency and you have 2 conflicting versions in there, also the `taglibs-standard-impl` you have in there won't work, as that is for the old EL implementation. Remove the `version` from the `spring-session-data-redis`, you also don't need the `spring-boot-autoconfigure`. Less is more here.

Comment: @M.Deinum pom xml is updated but same error happen

Comment: The problem wasn't so much your pom (that was just an additional tip to clean up your pom). The problem is the absence of proper multi part configuration in your `application.properties`.

Comment: I set the application.properties already. But still not working. I've update the post

Comment: Do you have any `@EnableWebMvc` or the likes in your configuration? As that would disable the default configuration.

Comment: Theres no `@EnableWebMvc` in any location. Theres no `@Configuration` also at any location

Comment: Strange. Could you add your configuration that you have? I also wonder if the `javamelody-spring-boot-starter` is compatible you would at least need 2.1.0 for Spring Boot 3 I suspect. looking at your logging, the `mvc-dispatcher` isn't the name of the default Spring Boot `DispatcherServlet` so you have some additional configuration somewhere for another (or overridden) `DispatcherServlet`.